# Django: DetailView and two slug fields

Tags: python, django, slug

My database model has different organizers who can have several events. I now want to filter my `DetailView` down to organizer and then a specific event. My solution is that one here, but I still have in mind, that there shouldn't be two slug fields in the `get_object` method. Is there another approach to what I am trying to do?

views.py

```
class EventDetailView(DetailView):

    context_object_name = 'event'

    def get_object(self):
        organiser = self.kwargs.get('organiser')
        event = self.kwargs.get('event')
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(organiser__slug=organiser)
        return get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=event)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(
        '<slug:organiser>/<slug:event>/',
        EventDetailView.as_view(),
        name='event'
    ),
]
```

Comment: Why shouldn't there be two slug fields? This should work fine; what problems are you having with this code?

Comment: It actually works for me now, while writing it I just read that it should be done with one slug field only, but I think I just misunderstood it. Thank you for the answer Daniel!